# Rewrite each of the following sentences using logical connectives

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, logic-translation

Rewrite each of the following sentences using logical connectives. Assume that each symbol $f, x_0, n, x, S, B$ represents some fixed object.

> (a) If $f$ has a relative minimum at $x_0$ and if $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then $f’(x_0)=0$

a) (($f$ has a relative minimum at $x_0$) $\land$ ( $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$))$ \implies$ $f’(x_0)=0$

> (b) If $n$ is prime, then $n = 2$ or $n $ is odd.

b) $n$ is prime $\implies$ (($n = 2$) $\lor$ ($n$ is odd))

> (c) A number $x$ is real and not rational whenever $x$ is irrational.

c) ((A number $x$ is real) $\land$ $\lnot$ (rational)) $\iff$ $x$ is irrational.

> (d) If $x=1$ or $x=−1$,then $|x| =1$.

d) (($x=1$) $\lor$ ($x=−1$)) $\implies$ $|x| =1$

> (e) $f$ has a critical point at $x_0$ iff $f’(x_0) = 0$ or $f ′(x_0)$ does not exist.

e) ($f$ has a critical point at $x_0$) $\iff$ (($f’(x_0) = 0$) $\lor$ ($f ′(x_0)$ does not exist))

> (f) $S$ is compact iff $S$ is closed and bounded.

f) $S$ is compact $\iff$ (($S$ is closed) $\land$ (bounded)).

> (g) $B$ is invertible is a necessary and sufficient condition for $\det B$ not equal to $0$.

g) ($B$ is invertible) $\iff$ $\lnot (\det B= 0)$.

> (h) $6\geq n−3$ only if $n>4$ or $n>10$.

h) (($n>4$) $\lor$ ($n>10$)) $\implies$ (($6> n−3$) $\lor$ ($6=n-3$))

> (i) $x$ is Cauchy implies $x$ is convergent.

i) $x$ is Cauchy $\implies$ $x$ is convergent.

> (j) $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ whenever $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$

j) $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ $\iff$ \$lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$

> (k) If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f$ is strictly increasing at $x_0$, then $f′(x_0) > 0$.

k) (( $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$) $\land$ ($f$ is strictly increasing at $x_0$)) $\implies$ $f′(x_0) > 0$.

Comment: There is no indication in the sentence _(c)_ that **x is irrational** being a necessary condition for the **x is real and not rational**, otherwise the sentence would look like _x is real and not rational when and only when x is irrational_. So implication should be used instead of biconditional connective.

Comment: @anfauglit you are right, thanks

Comment: @Dima - In my answer I assumed that you are working in propositional logic, and then quantifiers are not allowed. This is consistent with the fact that "each symbol $f, x_0, n, x, S, B$ represents some fixed object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are correct, except (c), (h) and (j).

In (c) and (j), "whenever" stands for "if", i.e. it expresses a sufficient condition, which in general is not necessary. 
"$A$ whenever $B$" has the same meaning as "if $B$ then $A$".
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/711450/288417) for more details.

In (h), "only if" expresses a necessary condition, which in general is not sufficient.
It is the dual of "if": "$A$ only if $B$" has the same meaning as "if $A$ then $B$". 
A necessary and sufficient condition is expressed by "if and only if". 
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1935013/288417) for more details.

The correct translations of the sentences (c), (h) and (j) are the following (I assume you are not allowed to use quantifiers):

> (c) A number $x$ is real and not rational whenever $x$ is irrational.

c) A number $x$ is irrational $\implies$ (($x$ is real) $\land$ $\lnot$ ($x$ is rational))

or more precisely,

c') $x$ is a number $\implies$ ($x$ is irrational $\implies$ (($x$ is real) $\land$ $\lnot$ ($x$ is rational))).

> (h) $6\geq n−3$ only if $n>4$ or $n>10$.

h) (($6> n−3$) $\lor$ ($6=n-3$)) $\implies$ (($n>4$) $\lor$ ($n>10$)).

> (j) $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ whenever $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$

j) $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$ $\implies$ $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.